# flutter radio button select show hide

Tags: flutter

I'm beginner to flutter, I have some conflict on the show and hide flutter radio button select after display text filed, anyone know how to display when i `select yes` and then display `remark text filed`

**here the my code**

```
 class MyBookPage extends StatefulWidget {
          final BookDetails _bookDetails;
        
         MyBookPage(this._bookDetails);
        
          @override
       MyBookPageState createState() {
            return MyBookPageState();
          }
        }
        
        
        class MyBookPageState extends State<MyBookPage> {
          final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
          final TextEditingController _textNameController = new TextEditingController();
          final TextEditingController _textPhoneController =
          new TextEditingController();
          String _selectBookType = "";
          String title;
          @override
          void initState() {
            _textNameController.text = widget._bookDetails.fullName;
     
         
     }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return BlocBuilder<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text("Add New Book"),
                  ),
                  body: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: bookForm(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        
          Widget bookForm(BuildContext context) {
            final format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        
                children: <Widget>[
        
        
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                 
                  
                  FormBuilderRadio( activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Please Select Book type \*',
        
                      hintText: 'Please select book',
        
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                    attribute: "book_type",
                    validators: [
                      FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                    ],
                    options: [
                      "Yes",
                      "No",
                    ]
                        .map((lang) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                      value: lang,
                      child: Text(
                        lang,
        
                      ),
                    ))
                        .toList(growable: false),
                  ),
        
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    maxLength: 100,
                    /*  controller: _textNameController,*/
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        
                      hintText: ' please add here the reason',
                      labelText: 'Select Reason',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please add remark ';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
        
                  ),
        
        
        
        
        
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
        
                
                  SafeArea(
        
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                      child: Container(
        
                        height: 80,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: FlatButton(
                               onPressed: () {
        
                                 {
                                   AwesomeDialog(
                                       context: context,
                                       animType: AnimType.LEFTSLIDE,
                                       headerAnimationLoop: true,
                                       dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
                                       title: 'Successfully Submitted',
                                       desc:
                                       'Your data has been successfully submitted',
                                       btnOkOnPress: () {
                                         debugPrint('OnClcik');
                                       },
                                       btnOkIcon: Icons.check_circle,
        
                                       onDissmissCallback: () {
                                         debugPrint('Dialog Dissmiss from callback');
                                       })
                                     ..show();
                                 }
                            // It returns true if the form is valid, otherwise returns false
                        /*    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              print(_textPhoneController.value.text +
                                  "->" +
                                  _selectLeadType);
                              // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                              Scaffold.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Data is in processing.')));
                            }*/
        
                          },
        
        
                          child: Text("SUBMIT",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          color: m_primaryColor,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
        
                  ,
        
                ],
              ),
        
            );
        
          }
        
        
        }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem again? Please correct me if I am wrong - On radio button selection, you want to show/hide the Remark text field? Is that correct?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi , Here the issue, I want to know how to do, when I click on the radio button after display input flied, but first time don't wanna show input filed ,

Comment: You can use the `Visibility` widget. It takes in a `bool` value. Initially, you can set it to `false` & the widget will not be visible & once you click on the radio button, you can call `setState` & change the boolean value to `true`. This will show the input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Visibility` widget. It takes in a `bool` value. Initially, you can set it to `false` & the widget will not be visible & once you click on the radio button, you can call `setState` & change the boolean value to `true` inside the `onChanged` callback. This will show the input field.

Also, in the library, it says that `FormBuilderRadio` is deprecated so please use `FormBuilderRadioGroup`.

```
class MyBookPage extends StatefulWidget {
          final BookDetails _bookDetails;
        
         MyBookPage(this._bookDetails);
        
          @override
       MyBookPageState createState() {
            return MyBookPageState();
          }
        }
        
        
        class MyBookPageState extends State<MyBookPage> {
          final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
          final TextEditingController _textNameController = new TextEditingController();
          final TextEditingController _textPhoneController =
          new TextEditingController();
          String _selectBookType = "";
          String title;

          bool isVisible = false; // New <----------

          @override
          void initState() {
            _textNameController.text = widget._bookDetails.fullName;
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return BlocBuilder<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text("Add New Book"),
                  ),
                  body: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: bookForm(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        
          Widget bookForm(BuildContext context) {
            final format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        
                children: <Widget>[            
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),

                  FormBuilderRadioGroup( activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,  // New <----------
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Please Select Book type \*',
        
                      hintText: 'Please select book',
        
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                    attribute: "book_type",
                    validators: [
                      FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                    ],
                    onChanged: (value) { // New <----------
                      if (value == "Yes") {
                        setState((){
                          isVisible = true;
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() { 
                          isVisible = false;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    options: [
                      "Yes",
                      "No",
                    ]
                        .map((lang) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                      value: lang,
                      child: Text(
                        lang,
        
                      ),
                    ))
                        .toList(growable: false),
                  ),
        
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  Visibility(visible: isVisible,  // New <----------
                    child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    maxLength: 100,
                    /*  controller: _textNameController,*/
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        
                      hintText: ' please add here the reason',
                      labelText: 'Select Reason',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please add remark ';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
        
                  ),
                  ),
        
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),

                  SafeArea(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                      child: Container(
        
                        height: 80,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: FlatButton(
                               onPressed: () {
        
                                 {
                                   AwesomeDialog(
                                       context: context,
                                       animType: AnimType.LEFTSLIDE,
                                       headerAnimationLoop: true,
                                       dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
                                       title: 'Successfully Submitted',
                                       desc:
                                       'Your data has been successfully submitted',
                                       btnOkOnPress: () {
                                         debugPrint('OnClcik');
                                       },
                                       btnOkIcon: Icons.check_circle,
        
                                       onDissmissCallback: () {
                                         debugPrint('Dialog Dissmiss from callback');
                                       })
                                     ..show();
                                 }
                            // It returns true if the form is valid, otherwise returns false
                        /*    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              print(_textPhoneController.value.text +
                                  "->" +
                                  _selectLeadType);
                              // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                              Scaffold.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Data is in processing.')));
                            }*/
        
                          },
        
        
                          child: Text("SUBMIT",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          color: m_primaryColor,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
        
                  ,
        
                ],
              ),
        
            );
        
          }
        
        
        }
```